# Duplicate Code with different object types

Tags: java, rest, web-services, java-8, code-duplication

I have to write the code below a few times which violates "DRY" principle (getting a warning in IntelliJ about duplicate code). The only thing that changes is what gets passed into `objectMapper.writeValueAsString()`

How would I put this in a function that would accept different object Types so I don't violate DRY? I don't know what concept to look up so I apologize if this is a duplicate post. Thanks.

```
try(CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String bodyRequest = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(id);
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(bodyRequest, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
    request.setEntity(entity);

    try(CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)){
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            System.err.println(statusCode + ": " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Write a method which does most of the boiler plat stuff, into which you can pass the required information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it into a method. Be sure that anything passed into the method is in fact serializable.

```
public Object doSomething(Object id) {
    try(CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault()){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String bodyRequest = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(id);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(bodyRequest, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
        request.setEntity(entity);

        try(CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request)){
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                System.err.println(statusCode + ": " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this answer is too cheeky.

Comment: close to what I was thinking, although I was thinking to have this method *only* accept a String, but have other methods, that will *convert* some Objects to `String` before calling this method.

Comment: But doesn't this assume I am passing in the object of the same type?

Comment: All Objects inherit from `Object`

Comment: @ScaryWombat has an excellent point. Converting the object the String request body before passing it to this method would be more explicit, and therefore easier (less surprising) for the maintainer.

Comment: I did not know that. Did mostly C in college and Java was more self taught. Thank you both!

Comment: @ScaryWombat How would you convert it to String? Do you mean to extract the objectMapper.writeValueAsString(id)? Otherwise, the string conversion will change the semantics dramatically!